# apache tomcat 7 stops whenever request recieved

Tags: tomcat7, java

i m working on netbeans IDE 7.1 and using apache tomcat server 7.0.22.0

its normal whenever i deployed the project but whenever client side application requested for service tomcat server gets stop with following error

```
Mar 05, 2014 7:19:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
INFO: Undeploying context [/ServletsModule]
Mar 05, 2014 7:19:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor ServletsModule.xml from C:\Users\Prem Ostwal\.netbeans\7.1\apache-tomcat-7.0.22.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost
Mar 05, 2014 7:19:02 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase start
INFO: The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ServletsModule]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
Mar 05, 2014 7:27:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8084"]
.
..
...
Java Runtime Exception!
Mar 05, 2014 7:27:03 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 05, 2014 7:27:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Mar 05, 2014 7:27:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
INFO: Waiting for 1 instance(s) to be deallocated
Mar 05, 2014 7:27:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
INFO: Waiting for 1 instance(s) to be deallocated
Mar 05, 2014 7:27:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
INFO: Waiting for 1 instance(s) to be deallocated
Mar 05, 2014 7:27:06 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/ServletsModule] is still processing a request that has yet to finish. This is very likely to create a memory leak. You can control the time allowed for requests to finish by using the unloadDelay attribute of the standard Context implementation.
Mar 05, 2014 7:27:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8084"]
Mar 05, 2014 7:27:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 05, 2014 7:27:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8084"]
Mar 05, 2014 7:27:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

can anyone please help me

Comment: Java Runtime Exception! - the exception stack trace should be displayed somewhere, or you may find a crash dump in a file like hs_err_pidXXXX.log where you tomcat is running.